# Maximum crossings of curvature-constrained curve

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, plane-geometry

Let $C$ be a curve in the plane whose curvature is everywhere $\le 1$.
If $C$ has length $L$, what is the largest number of proper self-crossings
of $C$ as a function of $L$?

For example, the curve below has length $L=2 \pi (n + \epsilon)$
and has $n(n-1)$ proper crossings, where $n=5$ in the figure.
So this pattern achieves $L (L-2\pi) /(4 \pi^2))$ crossings as $\epsilon \to 0$,
and so grows quadratically in $L$.

---

[image: CrossingsCurveMax]

---

> **Q1**. Can anyone see a pattern that improves on the above curve?
>   E.g., can more than $20$ intersections be achieved with $L \approx 10\pi$?
>
> **Q2**. Can the number of crossings grow faster than $L^2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no upper bound. Consider the curve which runs along the circle
of radius $1+\epsilon$ and turns around this circle $n$ times. The length is $2\pi n(1+\epsilon)$,
and the curve has infinitely many self-crossings, and curvature less than $1$.
Now perturb the curve slightly, so that the curvature is still less than $1$,
but it has finitely many self-crossings.
It is clear that the number of self-crossing can be made as large as you want,
for every given $n$.